# Rx.NET Buffer with delay problem on quotes aggregation

Tags: window, buffer, system.reactive

I am using reactive library for 1-second bar aggregation based on symbol quotes (foreign exchange and CFD)

So far without success on `IAsyncEnumerable` extension, so I decided to replace pull with push strategy where reactive comes into the play with operators. Unfortunately I am not familiar with it and fell into another problems. Anyway I am very close to achieve the final result.

What I want to achieve is to group by symbol quotes based on "TickTime" for the same second. The problem which I am facing is delay between the quote time - TickTime from broker side and received time - ReceivedTime from channel (delay is approx. 10 to 30 ms). I tried with delay operator in combination with buffer (timespan duration) but I guess it isn't the right option. I know I should be using window operator but I do not know how, because reactive approach is something new to me and I am still learning.

Notice:
If no quote appear in 1 second the observable should post the empty list (some kind of timeout) and later updates is not possible in my situation.

Here is my short code

```
    await Task.Run(() => {
    
    var asset = symbol;

    var observable = streamQuotes.ToObservable()
        .Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(15))
        .Buffer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), Scheduler.Default)
        .Subscribe(quotes =>
        {
            var topic = Topic.ToObject($"{provider}-{asset}-{Topic.SECOND}-1");

            if (DebugMode)
                Logger.LogInformation(
                    $"{topic} {JsonConvert.SerializeObject(quotes, Formatting.Indented)}");

            //_ = AggregateAsync(topic, quotes, epochBegin, epochStep++), cancellationToken);
        });

    cancellationToken.Register(() => observable.Dispose());
    Subscriptions.Add(observable);

}, cancellationToken);
```

which produces this output:

```
  {
    "Id": 142,
    "Bid": 45282.72,
    "Ask": 45341.63,
    "Symbol": "BTCUSD",
    "Time": 1707431630102,
    "TickTime": "2024-02-08T22:33:50.102+00:00",
    "ReceivedTime": "2024-02-08T22:33:50.1187799+00:00"
  },
  {
    "Id": 142,
    "Bid": 45283.05,
    "Ask": 45341.96,
    "Symbol": "BTCUSD",
    "Time": 1707431630552,
    "TickTime": "2024-02-08T22:33:50.552+00:00",
    "ReceivedTime": "2024-02-08T22:33:50.5654973+00:00"
  },
  {
    "Id": 142,
    "Bid": 45283.86,
    "Ask": 45342.77,
    "Symbol": "BTCUSD",
    "Time": 1707431630591,
    "TickTime": "2024-02-08T22:33:50.591+00:00",
    "ReceivedTime": "2024-02-08T22:33:50.6046997+00:00"
  },
  {
    "Id": 142,
    "Bid": 45285.07,
    "Ask": 45343.98,
    "Symbol": "BTCUSD",
    "Time": 1707431630702,
    "TickTime": "2024-02-08T22:33:50.702+00:00",
    "ReceivedTime": "2024-02-08T22:33:50.7155601+00:00"
  },
  {
   "Id": 142,
   "Bid": 45284.73,
   "Ask": 45343.64,
   "Symbol": "BTCUSD",
   "Time": 1707431630753,
   "TickTime": "2024-02-08T22:33:50.753+00:00",
   "ReceivedTime": "2024-02-08T22:33:50.7658716+00:00"
  },
  {
    "Id": 142,
    "Bid": 45284.45,
    "Ask": 45343.36,
    "Symbol": "BTCUSD",
    "Time": 1707431630853,
    "TickTime": "2024-02-08T22:33:50.853+00:00",
    "ReceivedTime": "2024-02-08T22:33:50.866821+00:00"
  },
  {
    "Id": 142,
    "Bid": 45284.54,
    "Ask": 45343.46,
    "Symbol": "BTCUSD",
    "Time": 1707431631003,
    "TickTime": "2024-02-08T22:33:50.999+00:00",
    "ReceivedTime": "2024-02-08T22:33:51.005728+00:00"
  },
  {
    "Id": 142,
    "Bid": 45284.64,
    "Ask": 45343.55,
    "Symbol": "BTCUSD",
    "Time": 1707431631040,
    "TickTime": "2024-02-08T22:33:51.03+00:00",
    "ReceivedTime": "2024-02-08T22:33:51.0530009+00:00"
  },
  {
    "Id": 142,
    "Bid": 45284.64,
    "Ask": 45343.55,
    "Symbol": "BTCUSD",
    "Time": 1707431631040,
    "TickTime": "2024-02-08T22:33:51.05+00:00",
    "ReceivedTime": "2024-02-08T22:33:51.056112+00:00"
  }
```

The output is wrong because of last 2 objects in the list, which belongs to the next second.

Please help me to solve this issue or at least point me to the right direction.

Comment: Don't mix tasks and observables like this. You know you can await an observable? You can make this code much shorter and cleaner.

Comment: It's really hard to unravel your code without a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

Since the Delay and Buffer rely on a system timer that has an average accuracy of 15ms, your buffering will always slide from second to second as it goes.

You need to rely on absolute event times. Please see my example below which does not rely on timers, but only on absolute times.

```
static async Task Main()
{
    var rnd = new Random();

    var quotes = Observable
                .Interval(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(300))
                .Select(_ => rnd.NextDouble());

    var sub = quotes
                .Timestamp()
                .Do(x => Console.WriteLine($"{x.Timestamp:mm:ss.fff}: {x.Value:N}"))
                .GroupByUntil(
                    q => q.Timestamp.DateTime.AddSeconds(1).ToString("s"), 
                    g => Observable.Return(Unit.Default).DelaySubscription(DateTime.Parse(g.Key, null, DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal)))
                .Select(group => group.ToList())
                .Concat()
                .Subscribe(list =>
                {
                    if(!list.Any()) return;

                    Console.WriteLine($"{list.First().Timestamp:HH:mm:ss.fff}-{list.Last().Timestamp:ss:fff}: Count: {list.Count}, Open: {list.First().Value:N}, High: {list.Max(x=>x.Value):N}, Low: {list.Min(x=>x.Value):N}, Close: {list.Last().Value:N}");
                });

    Console.ReadLine();     
    sub.Dispose();              
}
```

Feel free to ask if need explainations.

**Update (relying only on "server" timestamp):**

```
static async Task Main()
{
    var rnd = new Random();

    var quotes = Observable
                .Interval(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(125))
                .Select(_ => rnd.NextDouble())
                .Timestamp(); // "server" timestamp

    using var groupLifetimeSink = new Subject<IObservable<int>>();
    
    using var sub = quotes
                .Do(x => Console.WriteLine($"{x.Timestamp:mm:ss.fff}: {x.Value:N}"))
                .GroupByUntil(
                    q => 
                    {
                        var leftMilliseconds = 1000 - q.Timestamp.DateTime.Millisecond;
                        groupLifetimeSink.OnNext(
                        Observable
                            .Return(q.Timestamp.DateTime.Second)
                            .DelaySubscription(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(leftMilliseconds))
                        );
                        return q.Timestamp.DateTime.Second;
                    },
                    g => 
                    {
                        groupLifetimeSink.OnNext(Observable.Return(g.Key));
                        return groupLifetimeSink.Merge().DistinctUntilChanged();
                    })
                .Select(group => group.ToList())
                .Concat()
                .Subscribe(list =>
                {
                    if(!list.Any()) return;

                    Console.WriteLine($"{list.First().Timestamp:HH:mm:ss.fff}-{list.Last().Timestamp:ss:fff}: Count: {list.Count}, Open: {list.First().Value:N}, High: {list.Max(x=>x.Value):N}, Low: {list.Min(x=>x.Value):N}, Close: {list.Last().Value:N}");
                });

    Console.ReadLine();                     
}
```

**One more variant, without grouping, but pure streaming**

```
static async Task Main()
{
    var rnd = new Random();

    var quotes = Observable
                .Interval(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(125))
                .Select(_ => rnd.NextDouble())
                .Timestamp(); // "server" timestamp

    using var bufferBoundary = new Subject<Unit>();

    quotes
        .Do(x => Console.WriteLine($"{x.Timestamp:mm:ss.fff}: {x.Value:N}"))
        .Scan((previous, current) =>
        {
            if (previous.Timestamp.ToString("s") != current.Timestamp.ToString("s")) bufferBoundary.OnNext(Unit.Default);
            return current;
        })
        .Buffer(bufferBoundary.Synchronize())
        .Subscribe(list =>
        {
            if (!list.Any()) return;

            Console.WriteLine($"{list.First().Timestamp:HH:mm:ss.fff}-{list.Last().Timestamp:ss:fff}: Count: {list.Count}, Open: {list.First().Value:N}, High: {list.Max(x => x.Value):N}, Low: {list.Min(x => x.Value):N}, Close: {list.Last().Value:N}");
        });

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: that's true, but this absolute times between broker server and my computer are different, still the same problem appear with snippet above, I should not rely on my system timestamp, but aggregate the tick time from broker with knowing that ticks come with the delay of some milliseconds

Comment: @Strausa This is the example, you can rely on message timestamp and make DelaySubscription with not absolute time, but something about 1.5 seconds or close previous group both on timeout OR when new group created - if you think that delay of 0.5 sec is too much for you

Comment: ok I got it, so I can modify and fine tune with subscription delay or timeout which I think will be needed. Thank you for the explanation.

Comment: @Strausa added more robust solution, a bit complicated this time

Comment: @Strausa Check more streamlined variant, pure stream without any GroupBy. And IMO - simpler and more clearly understandable

Answer (score 1):

This should probably solve it for you, or at least lead you down the right path:

```
var observable = streamQuotes.ToObservable()
    .GroupBy(q => q.TickTime.Ticks / TimeSpan.TicksPerSecond) 
    .SelectMany(g => g.Buffer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), Scheduler.Default).Take(2))
    .Subscribe(quotes =>
    {
        Console.Write(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(quotes, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented));

    });
```

A couple problems with your code:

1. It looks like you want to buffer / group by the seconds *value* of your `TickTime` property. The `Buffer` operator (and the `Window` operator as well) you're invoking will buffer by seconds offsets of whenever your code runs and data arrives. It doesn't look at your data at all.
2. You can use Buffer if you monkey with the window openings, but that's more trouble than it's worth.

The `GroupBy` in the solution first groups the data by the tick-based second value. The `Buffer` than takes those and forms it into a list. The `Take(2)` ensures that each window created by the `GroupBy` stays open for 2 seconds max to prevent memory leaks.

Comment: No need to mention that this has a memory leak because groups are not closed? :-)

Comment: Added fix for memory leak.

Comment: @Shlomo thanks for the exmaple, I am curious what does the Merge() do in this case?

Comment: The Merge was in error. I originally had a Select followed by a Merge, which can be simplified to just SelectMany.

Comment: @Shlomo Just one small comment here - closing the group using .Take(2) does not close the Subject backing GroupBy operator, so still a memory leak here

Comment: If that’s the case, then it’s an implementation bug on the library end. The GroupBy children would be unsubscribed observables which should not consume memory.

Comment: @Shlomo I'm not sure this is a bug because GroupBy is almost pure Subject, thus hot. Maybe you're right. Meanwhile added a variant without GroupBy operator

Comment: Your last solution will fail if there are any results out of order.

Comment: Sure. It relies on time ordered sequence

Comment: That’s not an assumption you should make when processing live tick data. There’s an easy way around the growing groups problem. I’ll post later.